# Homology of $n$-manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

$R$ is a ring with unity (if necessary, PID) and $G$ is any $R$-module

One known fact about homology of $n$-manifold is the following:

> If $X$ is $n$-manifold then for any $x_0\in X$,
> $$H_q(X,X\setminus\{x_0\};G)\simeq \begin{cases} 0 & q\neq n\\ G & q = n\end{cases}$$
> where $G$ is $R$-module.

I want something similar statement for $H_q(X;G)$ :

> If $X$ is a connected compact orientable $n$-manifold then
> $$ H_n(X;G)\simeq G$$

I added 'connected compact orientable' because it's those are necessary conditions I found so far.

I have two useful facts

> $\textbf{Fact 1.}$ If a compact connected $n$-manifold $X$ with boundary $\partial X$ is orientable over $R$ then $H_n(X,\partial X;R)\simeq R$.

> $\textbf{Fact 2.}$ If $X$ is a compact orientable manifold with boundary $\partial{X}$, then
> $$H^q(X;G)\simeq H_{n-q}(X,\partial{X};G)$$
> $$H^q(X,\partial{X};G)\simeq H_{n-q}(X;G)$$

Is the statement true? If so, how can I prove it?

Note. 1. The statement holds at least for connected closed orientable surface.
2. All those facts are stated in Spanier AT.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but what happens when you put $\partial X = \emptyset$ in Fact 1?

Comment: @OsamaGhani Then I think it's a statement for manifold without boundary.

Comment: What is your definition of a manifold? Do you allow boundary or not? Usually, compact manifolds without boundary are called *closed.* If in your question you mean a closed manifold then just use Fact 2 with $q=0$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan A topological $n$-mfd (without boundary) is a paracompact Hausdorff space in which each point has an open nbd homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. When the context says 'mfd with boundary' I'm allowing the possibility that the boundary is empty (so encompasses mfd without bdy.)

Comment: Ok, then just use Fact 2, as I said.

Comment: Ok, but for compact manifolds with boundary your question has obviously negative answer. All, in all, it is unclear to me if you have a question.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes yes. thanks.